# Generating JQuery script with php

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to write a jquery function with php but the function stops writing the jquery function half way through. When I start the while loop it seems to cause an internal server error 500

```
function loadSchedule() {
$id = $_SESSION['loginID'];
//query stuffs that works

$conn = getCon();

$res = $conn->query($qry);

echo "$(document).ready(function() {"
        ."$('#schedule').fullCalendar({"
        ."  header: {"
        ."  left: '',"
        ."  center: '',"
        ."  right: ''"
        ."},"

        ."defaultView: 'agendaWeek',"
        ."editable: false,"
        ."allDaySlot: false,"
        ."eventLimit: true," // allow "more" link when too many events
        ."events: [";

//problem starts here
while($rows = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    foreach (explode(',', $rows['DOW']) as $val){
        echo '{'
            .'title:"'.$rows['Course_code'].' '.$rows['number'].'",'
            .'start:"'.$rows['start'].'",'
            .'end: "'.$rows['end'].'",'
            .'dow: ['.getDayStr($val).'] '
            .'},';
    }
}                       
echo "]});});";
```

Whenever I comment out the while loop it works but otherwise it fails.
If I put this in a file on its own it works perfectly but for some reason it fails when put into a script tag.

Comment: But why? Wouldn't it be better to write the javascript in a javascript file, and then just output the PHP data to the DOM instead.

Comment: I agree with @adeneo . And you should check the error log.

Comment: That might be better but I am mimicing how a teammate set it up because I don't have time to do anything else right now. In theory php should be able to write a Jquery/javascript function. This function loads a table from data in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect an error in your SQL query. If the query fails, there will be an error at `while($rows = $res->fetch_assoc())`, beause `$res` is not an object. You can check this by replacing the while loop by `if (!$res) die('query failed '.$conn->error);`

Comment: did you check, if `getDayStr($val)` works? Maybe this is causing the error.

Comment: We were both sort of right. The query was wrong but not because of sql... I forgot to start the session.

Comment: I used a session variable in the query